# Determine $n$ trials with normal approximation of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let $p=0.1$ be the probability that a produced dice is broken. I now want to calculate how many dices have to be produced to assure with at least $99$% probability that at least 1000 dices are not broken.

This obviously follows a binomial distribution: $X \sim  Bin(n, 0.9)$, where $n$ is the variable I want to determine. I know that for large $n$ we can approximate by a normal distribution.

$$\mathbb{P}(X \geq 1000) \geq 0.99 => 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1000 - 1) \geq 0.99 => 1 - \Phi(\frac{999-0.9n}{\sqrt{0.9n(1-0.9)}}) \geq 0.99$$

How can I determine $n$?

Comment: For large $n$ the process is nearly normal with mean $\mu=p\times n$ and $\sigma=\sqrt {n\times p\times (1-p)}$. (where, in your case,  $p=.9$). I'd just search numerically around the case where $\mu-2\sigma\approx 1000$.  That comes to around $1133$ , and the search shows that $1126$ is good enough.

Comment: Sorry, that answer was for $90\%$.  If we want $99\%$ we have to go a little deeper, though $1138$ is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1-\Phi\left(\frac{1000-0.9n}{\sqrt{0.1n(1-0.1)}}\right)\geq 0.99$$
is equivalent to 
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{1000-0.9n}{\sqrt{0.1n(1-0.1)}}\right)\leq 0.01
$$
Use table of standard normal distribution or Excel function **Norm.S.Inv** to get
$$
\frac{1000-0.9n}{\sqrt{0.1n(1-0.1)}}\leq \Phi^{-1}(0.01)\approx-2.326
$$
And then solve quadratic inequality with respect to $\sqrt{n}$
$$
1000-0.9n \leq -2.326 \sqrt{0.09n}=-2.326\times0.3\sqrt{n}
$$
The result is $n\geq 1137.26$. Since $n$ is integer, we should take $n\geq 1138$.

We can also check the accuracy by Excel function **Binom.Dist**: 
$$=1-\text{BINOM.DIST}(999;1138;0.9;1) = 0.991376330173266 > 0.99,$$ 
and 
$$=1-\text{BINOM.DIST}(999;1137;0.9;1) = 0.989229871716899 < 0.99.$$

Comment: If $n=1023$ then the expected number of unbroken dice is $.9\times 1023=920.7$.  Thus the probability that there are at least $1000$ unbroken dice in that sample would be significantly below $.5$

Comment: @NCh I made a typo in my original post. One needs to use $0.9$ and not $0.1$ since $p$ is the probability that a dice is broken and we want the opposite.

Comment: In your quadratic inequality, it should be $-2.326\sqrt{0.09n}$.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, thank you!

Comment: @lulu, you are really right.

Comment: @lulu And I answered only on the OP question: what to do next and how to find $n$.

Comment: @NCh Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. PS: I also forgot that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 1000) \geq 0.99 => 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1000 - 1) \geq 0.99$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 1000) \geq 0.99 => 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1000) \geq 0.99$

Comment: This is not critical since normal distribution is continuous. And you can also check the accuracy by Excel function Binom.Dist: =1-BINOM.DIST(999;1138;0.9;1) = 0.991376330173266 > 0.99, and =1-BINOM.DIST(999;1137;0.9;1) = 0.989229871716899 < 0.99.